# Weird Issue with Javascript object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Apologies in advance if this is an obvious issue. I have done as much searching as I could putting this issue into search terms.

I have the below block of code which is supposed to create a Google maps marker for each 'transponder' if there has not been one added previously. However every time this block of code runs it doesn't detect the previously created marker stored in the transponder object and recreates it.

This is despite seeing the marker within the transponder object in the DOM view of Firebug.

```
function addOrUpdateTransponderPostionRpt(transponderPositionRpt) {
var t = getTransponderById(transponderPositionRpt.TransponderId);
  if (t) {
    console.log("Found Transponder: " + t.Id);
    if (t.gMapMarker) {
        console.log("Transponder has existing marker, updating: " + t.Id);
        moveMarker(t.gMapMarker, new google.maps.LatLng(transponderPositionRpt.Latitude, transponderPositionRpt.Longitude));
    } else {
        console.log("Transponder has no existing marker, creating: " + t.Id);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(transponderPositionRpt.Latitude, transponderPositionRpt.Longitude),
            map: map,
            title: t.DefaultNickname    
        });
        t.gMapMarker = marker;
    }
  }
}
```

debug output from the javascript (the same every time)

- Found Transponder: 4
- Transponder has no existing marker, creating: 4
- Found Transponder: 6
- Transponder has no existing marker, creating: 6

Can anyone help ? :)

**EDIT: Additional methods referenced in this code block:**

```
function getTransponderById(id) {
var ret;
$.each(transponders, function (i, item) {
    if (transponders[i].Id == id) {
        ret = transponders[i];
        return;
    }
});
return ret;
}

function moveMarker(marker, newPosition) {
    marker.setPosition(newPosition);
}
```

Comment: I am wondering if at some point rather than passing an object it's copying it? As I understand it there is no way in JS to pass an object as a reference just to be sure.

Comment: When you find transponders id, after `ret = transponders[i];` you return nothing. There should be `return ret`.

Comment: getTransponderById() works perfectly by itself, I return nothing as it breaks the iteration, the value is assigned to a variable outside the iteration scope for the method to return. If it doesn't find a transponder with the requested ID then its ok to return nothing.

Comment: its working fine - http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/pQFs4/3/
the problem might be something else..

Comment: Now this is really weird, I copy the same javascript from the method and run it within the firebug console... Works perfectly! call it within a method though and it doesn't work as described!

Comment: I never worked out what the error was, I just re-wrote everything from scratch and problem is gone :D

thanks everyone.